# How to get specific property from Google Spreadsheet JSON feed

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am reading JSON from a Google Spreadsheet and need help getting to the text within entry.content.$t.  The text is a column named "description" in the spreadsheet. The feed for the spreadsheet is (removed)

So far, my script is

```
function listChapters(root) {
    var feed = root.feed;
    var entries = feed.entry || [];
    var html = ['<ul>'];
    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
        var chlist = entries[i];
        var title = (chlist.title.type == 'html') ? chlist.title.$t : escape(chlist.title.$t);
        var chapters = chlist.content.$t;
        html.push('<li>', chapters, '</li>');
    }
    html.push('</ul>');
    document.getElementById("chapterlist").innerHTML = html.join("");
}
```

The question is - How do I read "description" from $t to place in the var chapters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text within `chlist.content.$t` is almost, but not quite, properly formatted JSON. Since it's not properly formatted, you cannot use `JSON.parse()` to create an object that you could then get a `description` property from.

Here's a brute-force approach that will extract the `description`, used in place of the original `html.push('<li>', chapters, '</li>');`:

```
// Get the text between 'description: ' and 'Chapter website:'
var descStart = chapters.indexOf('description:')+13;  //+length of 'description: '
var descEnd = chapters.indexOf('Chapter website:');
var description = chapters.substring(descStart,descEnd);

html.push('<li>', description, '</li>');
```

Tested with this, checking results in debugger:

```
function test() {
  var url = '---URL---';
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var text = result.getContentText();
  var bodytext = Xml.parse(text,true).html.body.getText();
  var root = JSON.parse(bodytext);
  listChapters(root);
}
```

Comment: That gets me very, very close.  I need all the text after the word description.  This field in the spreadsheet is the results of a script that combines all the other fields in the row, formats them, and excludes columns on records that don't have an entry in that column.

I was able to get what I needed using 'code'var description = chapters.substring(descStart);'code'

Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad to help! You might want to un-publish that sheet, or obfuscate the contact info in it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I removed the link from my original posting.